# Pass array data to matdialog in angular

Tags: angular

I want to pass array data to Matdialog using angular ,for single data it working but how to pass array data.

My component where i call dialog

distributor-order.component.ts

```
openDialog(address, city, pin, phone, orderid, orderstatus, totalprice, updateby, updatedate): void {
    console.log(address);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(OrderDialogComponent, {
       width: '1000px',
       data: {
           Address: address, 
           City: city, 
           Pin: pin, 
           phone:phone,
           Orderid: orderid, 
           Orderstatus: orderstatus,
           Totalprice: totalprice,
           Updateby: updateby,
           Updatedate: updatedate
       }
   });
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      //this.animal = result;
   });
}
```

Here how can i send array data with this single data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed the array inside the data-object - the same way you are sending any other data to the dialog. Then you can get it inside the dialog with **this.data.arrayForDialog** in this case.

```
openDialog(address, city, pin, phone, orderid, orderstatus, totalprice, updateby, updatedate): void {
    let myArray = [{name: 'jon'}, {name: 'bob'}];
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(OrderDialogComponent, {
       width: '1000px',
       data: {
           arrayForDialog: myArray,
           Address: address, 
           City: city, 
           Pin: pin, 
           phone:phone,
           Orderid: orderid, 
           Orderstatus: orderstatus,
           Totalprice: totalprice,
           Updateby: updateby,
           Updatedate: updatedate
       }
   });
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      //this.animal = result;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.